# How to recover lost files after an install

Tags: system-installation

I'm a newbie learning along the way. I recently installed a 2nd hdd into my ubuntu box. Have one of about 160g which runs ubuntu 12.04. And the new hdd was 1 tb, used for holding videos. I had set up 2nd drive as ext3 I believe. And set up folders on it to hold the videos. Worked great.

Also thought I had set it up for auto mount. I was able to read and write on it. Etc. Computer froze, so had to reboot it. When I did, system would not reboot: hung on the Ubuntu screen with 5 dots. I hit a few buttons and the command screen showed up, indicating that my 2nd hdd would not mount. Stopped up whole system. Tried rebooting, no go.

Had to reinstall ubuntu on the 1st hdd. Did not apparently touch the 2nd one. Well, when I got it up and running, my 2nd hdd mounted automatically (yeah!), but now I cannot find my videos I already had on it. I had not put any more than about 30g of videos on it, but now when I read its Properties, it says I'm using about 50g. So, I'm wondering if somewhere in that, buried, are my 17 videos.

Any help in recovering this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are some paid recovery tools such as R-studio for linux would be perfect. Also, they have a free edition called rlinux [try it](http://r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/Download.shtml)

Comment: Why direct users to closed source software when we do have a bunch of Open Source alternatives?

Comment: He is a newbie and working with tools you have provided need some skills which i am not sure he has it and my attitude to help in solving his problem first of all and you are right its better to direct to open source tools

Comment: I don't see where r-tools is easier to use than e.g. Testdisk but that may be personally biased.

Comment: Thank you. So, when I re-installed 12.04 on 1 hdd, did it do something to the other hdd (the newer one)? I just don't understand enough about the workings of this.

Comment: No, i dont think so?! Have you try the tool?

Answer (score 0):

Use file recovery tools for restoring accidentally overwritten or damaged hard drives.

The Ubuntu Community Wiki lists tools available:

- [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)

We have good experience with recovering partitions using Testdisk or individual files with PhotoRec.

- [Is there a way to recover files from a storage device partially overwritten with dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with)

[image: Install via the software center]