# dd'ed the first 200MB of a HDD, is the filesystem recoverable?

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

In a moment of stupidity I let a script run `dd` on one of my (non backed up :() HDD's, 3TB in size. It had a single ext4 filesystem on it, which now won't mount.

Things I've done so far (without success) from reading other people's misery:

1. made a backup of the drive to an image with `dd`.
2. ran `testdisk` on the drive, this produced around 20 lines of the following when running Analyse (both quick and deep): `ext4                0 0 1 364801 80 63 5860533168 [files]`. It won't let me fix it because it says writes aren't allowed when `None` is picked, any other combination of choices seems to be fruitless too (e.g. tried choosing Intel in the partition type, still a no go). By the way, `files` is the name of my old partition.
3. tried to mount the drive with a backup superblock as shown here:

   ```
   $ sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc
   mke2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
   /dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition!
   Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
   Filesystem label=
   OS type: Linux
   Block size=4096 (log=2)
   Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
   Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
   183148544 inodes, 732566646 blocks
   36628332 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
   First data block=0
   Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
   22357 block groups
   32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
   8192 inodes per group
   Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
       32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
       4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
       102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544
   ```

   this kept saying `wrong filesystem type` when running `mount`.
4. created a GPT partition table with `gparted` and tried to run fsck with a backup superblock, which had a lot of prompts and really weird numbers that didn't make any sense.

So I'm close to giving up unfortunately, because using `photorec` to try to extract the files without the directory structure is just going to be too time consuming.

Is there anything else worth trying that I haven't tried/did wrong?

Comment: Short of trying to recreate the first 200MB from an identically formatted drive and then run testdisk, I can't really think to anything... sorry.

Comment: related if not a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with - I believe if testdisk can't recover your partitions you may have no other choice than with photorec but let's see if someone has a better idea.