# Recover files deleted from Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 64Bits

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, eclipse, data-recovery

I was working in Eclipse when I clicked delete to only 1 project, and it deleted all of them on my workspace.

Could I recover data being a non specific extension ?? (I want to recover png, xml, class, package...).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the disk and don't write any file on the disk you want to recover

Only then make sure that the remainders of the lost files are not overwritten. The less was written in addition on that disk the more chance you have to recover some of your files by data recovery tools such as Testdisk/Photorec ([testdisk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk]).

Testdisk should be installed and run from booting with a live CD. Have another drive at hand where you can store the recovered files.

See also: [Is there a way to recover files from a storage device partially overwritten with dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with).

Comment: impossible, can't undelete