# Recovering data from corrupted partition

Tags: files, data-recovery

I tried to resize partition from 215 GB to 120 GB but linux mint launched from usb (i have got ubuntu on hard drive) froze and kdeparted stopped working at 66%. There are unallocated space and unknown filesystem. Is there any way to recover data from this unknown filesystem?

Comment: Sorry, your question is about Linux Mint so is off-topic on AskUbuntu.  Linux Mint is not accepted as an official "daughter" of Ubuntu. Go to the Unix and Linux SE website here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, it's a good thing that you have updated your question. In case of multiple distributions, don't rely on people to assume that you also use Ubuntu. But always do mention it in your question. Otherwise, your question will be suspended of being off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to recover files from a storage device partially overwritten with dd?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with)

Comment: You don't mention the original file system. Was it EXT4 or something else?